# Syntax Error in Solidity: Expected '(' but Got ')' - How to Fix?

Tags: debugging, ethereum, blockchain, solidity

`Hi, i upgraded my code to solidity 0.6.0; and i have this error : Expected '(' but got ')'solidity.

I can't figure it out !

If someone could help me understanding why this happen.

Here is the function :

```
function _delegate(address implementation) internal {
    assembly {
    // Copy msg.data. We take full control of memory in this inline assembly
    // block because it will not return to Solidity code. We overwrite the
    // Solidity scratch pad at memory position 0.
        calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize)

    // Call the implementation.
    // out and outsize are 0 because we don't know the size yet.
        let result := delegatecall(gas(), implementation, 0, calldatasize, 0, 0)

    // Copy the returned data.
        returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize)  // error

        switch result
        // delegatecall returns 0 on error.
        case 0 { revert(0, returndatasize) } 
        default { return(0, returndatasize) }
    }
}
```

if someone can figure it out ! do i have to send the full code ?`

Answer (score 0):

Assembly within Solidity 0.6 requires all function calls with parentheses, even though they don't accept any arguments.

E.g. `calldatasize()` instead of `calldatasize`, and `returndatasize()` instead of `returndatasize`.